# URL Rewrite not working as expected with multiple parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create a clean url along these lines
    http://example.com/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/

and with the following URL Rewrite rule, it appears to work fine

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^-]+)/([^-]+)/([^-]+)/([^-]+)/?$ /api.php?Key=$1&user=$2&funct=$3&request=$4 [L,QSA]
```

as i get the following output confirmation from a url rewrite tester.

```
http://example.com/api.php?Key=secretkey&user=username&funct=apifunction&request=data_in
```

where it appears to fall over however and the part I am struggling to understand is if I put an extra /moredata/ on the end of the URL it all falls to pieces. and the url rewrite tester shows that my url now returns as follows.

```
http://example.com/api.php?Key=secretkey/username&user=apifunction&funct=data_in&request=moredata/
```

any suggestions on where i am going wrong would be greatly appreciated, and any standout mistakes in my rewrite (this is all new to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^-]+` means match until next `-` is found or line end. But in your case you're actually matching URL components separated by `/`.

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apitest/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ api.php?Key=$1&user=$2&funct=$3&request=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I've tried this rule just before posting as i wondered if it was related to the - in the `[^-]`, however the rule no longer matches when i try this.

Comment: not really, this is the .htaccess file
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /apitest/api.php?Key=$1&user=$2&funct=$3&request=$4 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>`

the page is located at `http://localhost/apitest/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/moredata/`

Comment: I get the following error when I try to call the page

`The requested URL /apitest/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/moredata/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: ok so if i use your rewrite rule in /apitest/.htaccess and I call the following URL  

`http://localhost/apitest/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/`

it does load the page and I get the correct data returned, if I change it to 

`http://localhost/apitest/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/moredata/`

I then get

`Not Found

The requested URL /apitest/secretkey/username/apifunction/data_in/more/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: ok so you were almost spot on for what i wanted to-do after some tinkering with your updated rewrite code i've got it working.

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /api.php?apiKey=$1&user=$2&funct=$3&request=$4 [L,QSA]`

thank you for point me in the right direction and helping out!

Comment: Sorry just got back. I thought using `/moredata/` was just a hack you didn't intend to match that part. But yes you got it right by adding `(.*)` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 key things that is creating this behavior:

1. Your regex groupings are `([^-]+)` which means: "match anything except a `-` character"
2. The regex matching is greedy by default, meaning that it will match as much as it can.

This means that your first grouping, `([^-]+)` is matching both path elements as well as the `/`. If you really want to match everything except `-` characters, then include a `/` in all of them except the end:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^-/]+)/([^-/]+)/([^-/]+)/([^-]+)/?$ /api.php?Key=$1&user=$2&funct=$3&request=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: the regex is from a tutorial I've been reading on url rewrite (as regex is another part I am reading up on to get this working). I don't have a need to exclude the - character in my URL's ideally i need to match everything between each /,